# What's the fastest free software to test primality of a Mersenne prime?

Tags: math-software, primality-test, mersenne-numbers

Mersenne primes are primes of the form $2^n-1$ for positive integer $n$. Currently, the most widely known (and employed) software for testing large Mersenne prime candidates is [Prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/), which is also the software used by the GIMPS distributed project.

Unfortunately, even though Prime95 is marketed as "free", it is not in fact entirely free. For instance, the software's terms and conditions restrict the amount of prize money that can be won when discovering primes by taking a big chunk for the profit of GIMPS.

I am interested in other fast software that is specifically designed to prove the primality of Mersenne primes (using a variant of the Lucas-Lehmer test) and is *free*. It would also be useful to compare such software by performance, i.e., the time required to prove the primality of a given Mersenne prime for given CPU.

What are some fast and free software to test primality of a Mersenne prime?

Comment: pfgw is quite fast, but probably too slow to find a record prime alone.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: @Peter It looks like pfgw uses "*deterministic classical tests wherever possible and allows probable prime tests of arbitrary expressions*". I see not mention of an LL test, and without an LL test it would take eons to test a $10^{8}$ digit candidate Mersenne prime.

Comment: The Lucas Lehmer test is however not much faster, but the advantage is that it proves the primality. Finding a record prime will be extremely difficult whatever test you use.

Comment: With a single machine, already 200k digits is a "painful" magnitude.

Comment: @Peter I am not interested in testing a range of candidate primes, just one. According to the discoverer of $M_{49}$, testing his candidate prime using Prime95 took $31$ days on an Intel i7 4740K CPU. That does not seem "extremely difficult".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77521/discussion-between-peter-and-preservedfruit).